# How to guide TS compiler to infer proper type for typed property `T`?

Tags: typescript

I have `isUndefined<T>(...)` which with some type doesn't behave as intended, for simple type removes `undefined` for more complex doesn't:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/LAKAJgpgxgNghgJwgAgGYFcB2UAuBLAe02QDk58A3CAZRwITgHMa4qAKAawgE8AuZAM44EeTIwA0yPDggBbfgEkZsgJTJ+FAnjABuUKBzcADiiVzkAXmQBvZAG1RkAB78hIsQF1Xw0Y2QAfZEx0WQAjCAQA5FCCAhgIOGIAXz0QQxNkanQjI3oZMABpHgFLG3suPkEfT35aeiYIM1lkFINjFCycvIgwAB4C5AgnGUwwEs7chHyi7gEAPlKKglRkAYAyKvdGVPSOugZmJtLbOCgoCAEBfhi4hMxJMHI4RWUorEhUUR6WnfbM-YaTQAIk9egpBsMIKNxgDDsoFlYFHYAESPHBwZEeX4ZADiEBwTQAShd0DAcGCISMxv96nC5AiaQdGsoQeiwQtAu8IJ9MD1Um0MgBhRDHZCyAiQGDeLaSKBxejS3ySIwICXoXCETCsiD8YJhCI-AUoAAKEQERFFmDgsh1myVgnQCCtNsVYkkDV1IXCkVaaT+E26hWKClkRniNsw6PwFqsoGsoGQieQyKgiGR-BOZwuV2QwnQEAeT34wp9qSTyZMCHNmHTZVO50u-FQcBgAgLyDRz2QpqrFt9SX0IAw2GjxDwAgAqqNuV8+gAVOZsCgt-P8Odvac8npqDQrlDj5BcrdgOMJpN4VBsXbLZDLmD5ywWKzIo+z5FqJA4R3EPMQMtJz9vzQFs21SAcQFAWA4EuZBBXQIQCFkOomV6agAFlKShakAymHoZnmU8QHLNsCWUfpMOhTJskmfJULQuZFwqfgCkLdFalhZk5FZOA6LsAoPDmHdby0E8iKTeMxPLRMAHppOQAAJCIUBVAhQnDZACDOR1+FEVAIiQMBkFTGAYCkEpxynD5Z1QjjgVBdC+IExcADpXLUAALKFzjPKTkFk5AAANoIER0em4gLcz+A8AuQwEWXstDHI5GwkgigBaBYAqOTlN1nKJrFS8QfKk-zX15QzdmQAB3aDMAAchwZAkHFKgwGc4ry38gBRJwTFwb5wnc1hCEicd+CQc0YCoQLYrpWRuN4-i5giuhkAywLssPXLyoCyQcE8zAOqTfzdP075jNMqq8BM6JoEQ-dJ22nowXhJc9xecwcqs8qVD2g7AuC0KwHCo6ZLkq6bvCOUbQ215AgKgL2skqS5UwIRkEBgzuNKCynrANhOzUAB+FL1A7J4dD8uT5IAeQAdWQOcaeQNCAEECi6xn5IUahkDpmnCQKInQdIcg8CoWaWHYCp3UuIHuJUf9fP83zVdVgA9EnBzV-zwQ4TACCqjSqAYG7JvQUdJFCC3kHBGrI1zAgjKGsQUAC3Hvp6CLhw1IheBF-zUfR1MhDCp4yc2srvisTslZKuSg8azGw-RHHHs9-GQ-yBXkBJgqydj4rwPLYrmFIuRyKGKkSiWFZ0MYnhmKEvFy9kYkQrJRaBOKiS1cAp1kAARgAJgAZgAFgAVgANgAdgADgATgxkosH1w3iGg5AW6JElO4cpa4-A8DQB90cxTgUQ2BUQjy0TjtuTgUkcBLUVxUlfhkTnC54GRWV5QQJ-AAQvAKAHA-7IBUmAdUo5tT8GHgABgQYPQ0yN74ISZKUXkRs4IISQhxVC1FAz4RDGGOQUIoyakXIrYq99UyRCsBghozky5NDYCmNMNDkb+U8kgQYJtuD7V8NVegHAShbn9mgog6Nk5gFflYD2M5ypsHocTB+zZn6v34PQymJ1MB6QQAZIyLYpRmUsko56JYXJuVodI24zkYAEEYGwWRJZFbIGKirNWiZNagBPiAWQl9MDX35BBMJg4IkgCAA)

```
declare function NativeStorageSave(key: string, item: Item) : void;

type Item = { [index: string]: string | number | boolean };
type SupportedKeys = { [key: string]: StorageItem };
type Supported<K extends SupportedKeys> = keyof K & string;
type StorageItem = { access: boolean, data: Item | undefined };
type StorageItemData<I extends StorageItem> = I["data"];
type GetItemResult<I extends StorageItem> = StorageItemData<I> | undefined;

type Car = { model: string, color: string, productionDate: number };
type Person = { name: string, surname: string, age: number };
type SupportedKeysImplementation = 
{
    "car": { access: true, data: Car };
    "person": { access: false, data: Person };
}

function isUndefined<T>(value: T | undefined) : value is undefined
{
    if(typeof value === "undefined") return true;
    return false;
}

class CustomStorage<SM extends SupportedKeys>
{
    setItem<K extends Supported<SM>>(key: K, data: StorageItemData<SM[K]>) : void
    {
        // Here problem occur: inferred call is isUndefined<StorageItemData<SM[K]>>(...) hence
        // `assuredData` type is `StorageItemData<SM[K]> | {}` -> `Item | undefined | {}`,
        // undefined type wasn't removed.
        // Expected behavior is: resolve `StorageItemData<SM[K]>` to -> `Item | undefined`, then
        // inferred call will become isUndefined<Item>(value: Item | undefined), then `assuredData`
        // will become `Item | {}`.
        const assuredData = isUndefined(data) ? {} : data; // HOW TO MAKE THIS WORK?
        NativeStorageSave(key, assuredData);
        //                     ^? 

        // I know overall solution, but I want to change `isUndefined` function:
        // const castedData : Item | undefined = data;
        // const assuredData = isUndefined(castedData) ? {} : data;
    }
    
    getItem<K extends keyof SM>(key: K) : GetItemResult<SM[K]>
    {
        return 123456789 as unknown as GetItemResult<SM[K]>;
    }
}

function main()
{
    const defaultCar = { model: "Tesla", color: "Black", productionDate: 2001 };
    const storage = new CustomStorage<SupportedKeysImplementation>();
    const car = storage.getItem("car");
    // here everything works fine:
    const assuredCar = isUndefined(car) ? defaultCar : car; // inferred call: isUndefined<Car>(...)
    console.log(assuredCar); 
    //            ^?
}

main();
```

Like I write in comment, the problem lays with type information for `T`. But why TS can't reasons about `StorageItemData<SM[K]>`? There is any way to implement `isUndefined<T>(...)` in the way to handle situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript isn't smart enough to detect negative type assertions through function calls.

You could instead inline the type assertion:

```
const assuredData = typeof data === "undefined" ? {} : data;
```

Or negate it:

```
function isNotUndefined<T>(value: T) : value is T & {} & null
{
    return typeof value !== "undefined"
}
```

```
const assuredData = isNotUndefined(data) ? data : {};
```

Comment: I like idea with `isNotUndefined<T>(...)`.

Comment: `Typescript isn't smart enough to detect negative type assertions through function calls.` this is not true for simple union type. Second `isUndefined(car)` call (for 'car'), properly removes `undefined` type.